# App Extension: multiple instances interfering with each other

Tags: ios, c, static-linking

I'm building an iOS App Extension (an Audio Unit plugin in this case). The code is a mix of Objective-C, C++ and C files.

When I run one instance of my Audio Unit in a host it works fine, but once I open another one the two instances start to interfere with each other. It seems that both instances are unexpectedly sharing some variables between them and I suspect it's happening somewhere in the C libraries I'm using.

I'm using lots of 'static' declared variables in my .m files to ensure they have file-scope. Am I right in assuming that each instance of the Extension will also have its own instance of each static variable, even when they are declared in a C library? Or is using C a bad architectural choice in this case?

Comment: In `C` `static` prevent link error for two global variables declared with the same name, but in different files. But these variables are still global per process, so if you call function `f` that use `static` variable from different instance of one class, `f` will the same global variable in both cases.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I'm misunderstanding how instantiating Extensions works. Apparently only one instance of the Extension is running, but inside it multiple instances of an internal class are created, sharing a bit of global code... I expected each Extension instance to be fully isolated as if they were two instances of the same application running side-by-side...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed multiple instances of the same Audio Unit Extension share the same process, which is extremely surprising and not documented anywhere (as if **anything** were documented regarding audio units at all!).